# How to find exact match of a column based on another column values on python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following sample dataframe with column A and B:

df:

```
A     B
123  555
456  123
789  666
```

I want to know which method can be used to print out *123* (a method to print out values of A which also exist in column B). I tried following:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
 if row.A in row.B:
    print(row.A, row.B)
```

but, got error: argument of type 'float' is not iterable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to print any row that row.A exists in column B, then your code should be:

```py
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.A in df.B:
        print(row.A, row.B)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this version too, but it does not print any output, neither any error.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with "dot" notation in dataframes, since columns can contain spaces and it starts to be a pain dealing with those. With that said,

Depending on how many rows you are iterating over, and the proportion of rows that contain unique values, it may be computationally less expensive to iterate over the unique values in 'A', and check if each one is in 'B':

```py
import pandas as pd
tmp = []
for value in df['A'].unique():
  tmp.append(df.loc[df['B']==value])
df_results = pd.concat(tmp)
print(df_results)
```

You could also use the built-in method .isin(), in fact, much of the power of pandas is in its array-wise operators, which are significantly quicker than most approaches involving loops:

```py
df.loc[df['B'].isin(df['A'].unique())]
```

And to only show one column with the ".loc" accessor, just add

```py
df.loc[df['B'].isin(df['A'].unique()), 'A']
```

And to just return the values in an optimized array

```py
df.loc[df['B'].isin(df['A'].unique()), 'A'].values
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Much helpful

Comment: @AytajAhmadova Glad to help, please consider accepting my answer if you found that is solved your problem!

Comment: will isin not match a substring as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
col_B = df['B'].unique()

val_B_in_A = [ i for i in df['A'].unique() if i in col_B ]
print(val_B_in_A)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned with an exact match try

`df['match'] = pd.Series([(df['col1']==item).sum() for item in df['col1']])`